# Unity swipe function using UI buttons and scrollview issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a code that allows me to swipe pages in my level selection menú with a scrollview, using buttons that modify the scrollbar value. It works perfectly when I press the button to go right, but using the same principle on the left button it doesn't work and it even make Unity freeze completely without giving me any error message.

Here right function:

```
    public void ScrollRight(Button button)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < button.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        if(button.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.GetChild(i).transform.name == button.transform.parent.transform.name)
        {
            i++;
            scrollPos = pos[i];
            Swipe(pos, i);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the left:

```
    public void ScrollLeft(Button button)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < button.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        if (button.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.GetChild(i).transform.name == button.transform.parent.transform.name)
        {
            i--;
            scrollPos = pos[i];
            Swipe(pos, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the Swipe:

```
    private void Swipe(float[] pos, int nextPosIndex)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pos.Length; i++)
    {
        if(scrollPos < pos[i] + (distance/2) && scrollPos > pos[i] - (distance / 2))
        {
            scrollbar.GetComponent<Scrollbar>().value = Mathf.Lerp(scrollbar.GetComponent<Scrollbar>().value, pos[nextPosIndex], 1f * Time.deltaTime);
        } 
    }
}
```

Also the needed variables:

```
    pos = new float[transform.childCount];
    distance = 1f / (pos.Length - 1f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code for left scroll, you increment `i` inside `for` statement, but then decrement it inside `for` body. As a result, your `i` is always equals 0, and `for` loop runs eternally.

In general, if you have unity freezed without error messages, and you dealing with loops, in most cases, it means that your loop set up not properly, and runs eternally.

Try something like this:

```
public void ScrollLeft(Button button)
{
    for (int i = button.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.childCount - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if(button.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.GetChild(i).transform.name == button.transform.parent.transform.name)
        {
            i--;
            scrollPos = pos[i];
            Swipe(pos, i);
        }
    }
}
```